# How can I translate these workplace goals into Japanese?

Tags: grammar, translation

I'm an ALT and my supervisor asked me to write my goals in Japanese this year. I'm trying to keep it simple, but I really struggle with putting English into Japanese.

Here is my attempt

> Deepen my relationship with students. Learn more about them and spend more time talking with them.
> 生徒とrelationship深まります。生活についてもっと知って行きたいと思います。
>
> Always be available to students. Encourage them to talk with me and ask me questions.
> 生徒に向かって助けることがいつでもできそうに進みたいです。私と話すし、私の質問をお勧めします。

Any help making these statements clear and acceptable for my supervisor to read would be much appreciated. Direct translation is not necessary at all, just a good, polite goal statement.

Answer (score 2):

> Deepen my relationship with students. Learn more about them and spend more time talking with them.
>
> 生徒達との人間関係をより深めたいと思います。そのためにも彼らとコミュニケーションを積極的にかわしていきたいです。

`生活についてもっと知って行きたいと思います。` sounds a bit odd to me. `生活について` sounds as if you are also interested in knowing their personal lives, e.g. when they sleep or wake up. Nothing wrong with that I guess, but it is probably not appropriate to say so in this situation. Also, you must say `彼らの生活` otherwise I have no idea whose or what `生活` you are talking about.

> Always be available to students. Encourage them to talk with me and ask me questions.
>
> いつでも生徒達からの要望に応えれるよう努めます。生徒達には何かあれば気軽に質問するよう勧めます。

I completely changed how you translated it because what you wrote didn't make sense grammatically, and it was hard to guess what you were trying to say without reading the original sentences.